# Protocol during antechamber heating

Tags: experimental-chemistry

I recently setup a heating apparatus for the large antechamber in my glovebox (i.e., large amounts of heating tape). Eventually, I want to do bake-outs for my moisture-sensitive chemistries (e.g., battery electrolytes).

What is the standard procedure for bake out in an antechamber? I know that many commercial entities like mBraun sell heating add ons for their boxes, so I'm sure that best practice exists.

Is it best that I put the chamber under slight vacuum so that pressure doesn't build up? Is it best that I keep argon in the chamber to help with heat transfer? What are other considerations I should have when running a bake?